# object of type float has no length

Tags: python

Code:

```
def is_english(nlp, text):
    '''Detect whether a text is English'''
    return nlp(text)._.language['language'] == 'en'

def extract_english_text(nlp, messages):
    '''Extract English text'''
    return [text for text in messages if is_english(nlp, text)]


english_messages = extract_english_text(nlp, message)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-adf8c0033ef3> in <module>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 english_messages = extract_english_text(nlp, message)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/language.py in __call__(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
    425         DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/language#call
    426         """
--> 427         if len(text) > self.max_length:
    428             raise ValueError(
    429                 Errors.E088.format(length=len(text), max_length=self.max_length)

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `message` with which you're calling `extract_english_text` is a string, and not a float? Can you share the bit of code where you define `nlp` and `message`?

Comment: I'm confused. Where exactly are you calling `len()`?

Comment: message=[]
for i in range(len(messages)):
  message.append(messages.iloc[i]['CONTENT'])

Comment: At least one of your `messages` is of type `float`, not `string`.

Comment: @VartikaV I see that code nowhere in your post.

Comment: hen what should i change steven

Answer (score 0):

Some of the `text`s passed into line 427 are of type `float`. There are two ways you could solve this:

1. You could find some way to gather only input of type `str`.
2. You could write code to check for other data types and either convert them to type `str` or raise an error using `try`/`except`. For that matter, you could do both, depending on the situation:

```
if type(text) != 'str':
    try:
        text = str(text)
    except:
        raise ValueError(f'Data type {type(text)} cannot be converted to a string.')
```

Comment: On second thought, it seems likely that all data types in Python can be converted to strings, in which case you would not need to use `try`/`except`.